# How to override error handler from a module

Tags: error-handling, module, yii2

To override error handler from a module based [this **samdark** guid](https://github.com/samdark/yii2-cookbook/issues/168):

```
class Module extends \yii\base\Module
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        \Yii::configure($this, [
            'components' => [
                'errorHandler' => [
                    'class' => ErrorHandler::className(),
                ]
            ],
        ]);

        /** @var ErrorHandler $handler */
        $handler = $this->get('errorHandler');
        \Yii::$app->set('errorHandler', $handler);
        $handler->register();
    }
}
```

This method only worked for **valid module controllers**, but can not handle **invalid module controllers**. Even affects all over the application so that module error handler will be default error handler all over the application. i was confused how can solve it!

Example: I was willing `www.site.com/module/x` handled with **module error handler**(www.site.com/module/default/error),where `x` is not a valid module controller. If that was not the case, it was handled with **app error handler**(www.site.com/site/error).

Finally i used this code: (`admin` is my module name). Know everything is fine.

```
class AdminModule extends \yii\base\Module
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        // Is better used regex method, temporally i used this method
        $r = Yii::$app->urlManager->parseRequest(Yii::$app->request)[0];
        $r_array = explode('/',$r);

        if($r_array[0] === 'admin'){
            Yii::configure($this, [
                'components' => [
                    'errorHandler' => [
                        'class' => ErrorHandler::className(),
                        'errorAction' => '/admin/default/error',
                    ]
                ],
            ]);

            $handler = $this->get('errorHandler');
            Yii::$app->set('errorHandler', $handler);
            $handler->register();
        }

    }
}
```

If you know a better way please share with me. Thanks

Comment: what does `if($r_array[0] === 'admin')` do for you in this context? if you're running the `Admin::init()` i would expect that the route requested starts with `admin`, does your code behave the same if you remove this condition?

Comment: If this line will don't check, error handlers don't act correctly. you can try it.
In this line we say the application replace the `errorHandler` component  only if route starts with `admin` module.
Before this code, i Wondering, why  `errorHandler` component  replaced with `admin` error handler when route not started with `admin`.